# Cannot convert <string>char to char

Tags: c++, stl, char

I am writing a function to encrypt using a cryptogram. I am getting a single error code that states that string char cannot be converted to char. I am not sure how to fix this. The error is in the second line in the else statement.

```
              else
                {
                  index=letter-96;
                  key[j]=words[index];
                }
```

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: `key[j]=words[index];` -- What is your intention on this line?  Did you lose track of what `key` is and what `words` is?

Comment: Which is it? `<string>char`? `string char`? maybe `string<char>`?

Comment: *string char cannot be converted to char. I am not sure how to fix this.* -- You cannot convert a string to a char, that should be obvious to you , i.e. you can't turn "abc" into a single character.  So the only one who knows "how to fix this" is yourself, since you should know what you were supposed to do on that line.

Comment: This is not a [MCVE]

Comment: Perhaps the question should be rolled back to the previous version. I am not sure why it was reduced to these 5 lines. No future reader could be helped by the question as it now stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
key[j]=words[index];
```

`key` is a

```
std::string key;
```

Therefore, `key[j]` is a `char`. `words` is a

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
```

Therefore, `words[index]` is a `std::string`.

You cannot assign a `std::string` to a `char`. C++ doesn't work this way. Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
char a;
std::string b;

a=b;
```

It is not clear what your intent is here, but, anyway, this answers why you're getting a compilation error.